# Как и какими инструментами узнать параметры GET запроса, отправляемого сайтом на движке WikiDot?

Tags: php, java, android, html

**Дано:**

[Сайт](http://scpfoundation.ru/) на движке `wikiDot`. На нём есть кнопка-ссылка на случайную статью сайта:

> https://scpfoundation.net/wikidot_random_page

При переходе по ссылке исполняется GET запрос и идёт перенаправление на сгенерированный каким-то образом (видать скрипт на сервере какой-то) URL адрес страницы на сайте.

**Задача:**

Программно получить случайный адрес страницы сайта по приведённой выше ссылке. При этом ни доступа ни к одному из сайтов и серверов указанных в вопросе.

**Возможное решение:**

Каким-то образом вызнать что происходит в браузере при переходе по ссылке и сформировать аналогичный запрос программно для получения итоговой случайной ссылки.

**Пробовал:**

- Гугл ответов не дал (гуглил как это на движке сайта делают).
- Попытка через инструменты разработчика хрома что-то выудить показала только, что по ссылке происходит GET запрос. Что там отправляется не видно (может плохо смотрел).
- Попытка загрузить ссылку программно не выдаёт никаких намёков на случайный URL.

**Вопрос:**

Как и какими инструментами можно выяснить что происходит в браузере при переходе по этой ссылке и как сэмулировать всё это для получения сгенерированного URL на кою перенапрвляет эта ссылка?

Comment: Если кликнуть в инструменте разработчика в Chrome на интересующий запрос, то он выдает все. И какой запрос и с какими заголовками и т.д.

Comment: @SergeyMitrofanov, точно, спасибо) Туда-то я и не догадался кликнуть)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На [java](/questions/tagged/java)

1. Согласно комменту @Sergey Mitrofanov, заголовки и прочую инфу о запросе и ответе можно просмотреть, если кликнуть в инструменте разработчика в Chrome на интересующий запрос.
2. Далее нужно составить `get` запрос с заголовками из п.1.
3. И, как верно заметил @VladD в своём ответе, обязательно нужно запретить автоматическое перенаправление.

Вот код на Java с использованием либы OkHttp:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .followRedirects(false)
        .build();

String url = "https://scpfoundation.net/wikidot_random_page";

Request.Builder request = new Request.Builder();
request.url(url);
request.addHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
request.addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
request.addHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8,de-DE;q=0.5,de;q=0.3");
request.addHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0");
request.get();

Response response = client.newCall(request.build()).execute();

Log.i("LOG", response.body().string());
//выдаст каждый раз разный URL для перенаправления:
//<html><body>You are being <a href="http://scpfoundation.ru/scp-851">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

На [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) покатит?

У меня вот такой код:

```
var address = new Uri("https://scpfoundation.net/wikidot_random_page");
var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { AllowAutoRedirect = false },
                            disposeHandler: true)
{
    DefaultRequestHeaders =
    {
        { "Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8" },
        { "Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br" },
        { "Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8,de-DE;q=0.5,de;q=0.3" },
        { "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0" }
    },
};
using (client)
{
    while (true)
    {
        Console.Write(address);
        var response = await client.GetAsync(address);
        switch (response.StatusCode)
        {
        case HttpStatusCode.Found:
        case HttpStatusCode.Moved:
            address = response.Headers.Location;
            Console.Write(" -> ");
            break;
        case HttpStatusCode.OK:
            Console.WriteLine(" (Finished OK)");
            return;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine($" (Finished with status {response.StatusCode})");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

выдаёт

> https://scpfoundation.net/wikidot_random_page -> http://scpfoundation.ru/scp-958-v (Finished OK)

(второй адрес всё время разный, разумеется).

Header'ы честно украдены у Firefox'а, флаг `AllowAutoRedirect = false` обязателен.

Comment: О, спасибо) Теперь буду пытаться это на java через OkHttp запилить) *прозрачно намекаю =)))

Comment: @ЮрийСПб: А что такое OkHttp? (Я-то в Java совсем профан.)

Comment: Это библиотека под андроид для работы с сетью. Уже всё получилось (благодаря вашему коду), ща свой отет с кодом запилю) И да - запрет автоперенаправления обязателен)

Answer (score 0):

Тоже самое на [php](/questions/tagged/php):

```
$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method' => 'GET',
        'follow_location' => false,
        'header' => "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n"
        . "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br\r\n"
        . "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,de-DE;q=0.5,de;q=0.3\r\n"
        . "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0\r\n"
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$html = file_get_contents('https://scpfoundation.net/wikidot_random_page', false, $context);

print $html . "\n";
```